# How do I make wordpress tag input box add a tag by pressing enter key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, events, jquery-events

I have the following text input inside a form that I would like be triggered after I press the enter key.  Please note that I can't use the ID to trigger this code. (ID changes on pageload)

```
<input type="text" id="cant_use" name="tmp_post_tag" value="" data
taxonomy="post_tag" data-taxtype="flat" class="wpt-new-taxonomy-title js-wpt-
new-taxonomy-title form-control wpt-form-textfield form-textfield textfield"    
data-wpt-type="textfield" data-wpt-id="cant_use" data-wpt-autocomplete="off">    
autocomplete="off">
```

The top code actually works IF it is not used inside the form, but on my wordpress site (plugin creates form) it does not.

This is the JS that has worked with an input, but without the form.

```
 $('input[name="tmp_post_tag"]').keypress(function(event) 
 {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);    
    if (keycode == '13'){ 
       alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');
    }   
 });
```

What conflicts could it be causing?